# Changing a item background

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to change background of an item in my app and I didn't found any thing about it. I use Item & menu for my drawer now I need to change titles background. I know that if use Listview I can change it but I want to now if there is a way for it. Thank you

```html
 <item
        android:checkable="false"
        android:title="@string/account">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_member"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_add_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/member" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_pay"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_credit_card_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/pay" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_fanclub"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_fanclub"
                android:title="@string/fanclub" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_introduction"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_introduction"
                android:title="@string/introduction" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_cards"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_cards"
                android:title="@string/cards" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_points"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_points"
                android:title="@string/points" />
        </menu>
    </item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Drawer menu is sadly not so easy to customize, you can not do it in the classic way du to a lack of parameters in its initial conception.

To do some you have to create a layout.xml exactly named as "design_navigation_item.xml"

then in this layout you should add your own ItemView extended class NavigationMenuItemView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    This layout should not be rename, It is use directly by design NavigationView component.
-->
<your.package.MyNavigationMenuItemView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingStart="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingEnd="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:focusable="true"/>
```

In your MyNavigationView class you can then override methods like

```
public class MyNavigationMenuItemView extends NavigationMenuItemView {

    private static final float MENU_ITEM_FONT_SIZE_SP = 14.0f;

    private CheckedTextView mTextView;

    public MyNavigationMenuItemView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyNavigationMenuItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyNavigationMenuItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        if (isInEditMode()) {
            return;
        }
        mTextView = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_menu_item_text);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(MenuItemImpl itemData, int menuType) {
         super(itemData, menuType);
         if (itemData.getTitle().equals("Some specific title") {
             // Do specific style changes on textview
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTextAppearance(int textAppearance) {
        // Text cutomization
        mTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, MENU_ITEM_FONT_SIZE_SP);
        mTextView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.menuItemBackgroundColor));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call `getActionView` method of `MenuItem` which will return you `View`. On that `View` you could change background color, like I did in below example -

```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   item.getActionView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, 
                                          R.color.colorAccent)); 
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

Comment: well You did it to change color when item would be selected. I want to change it permanently .